# 4awg Al on ground bar with 6awg max holes

Tags: wiring, grounding, subpanel

Im adding a subpanel, I installed a tgl2 (GE) ground bar that take 6awg max, my ser is a 2-2-2-4. Is there a way I can use this ground bar with a 4awg Al ? Also do I need to use some type of grease on my hot wires ?

Thanks for your help[image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside front of your panel please?

Comment: Make sure you catch our frequent cautions about getting an *extremely* large subpanel for what you consider your needs today. Getting more spaces *right now* is very cheap. Getting more spaces down the road when you have run out, is very expensive.  A panel whose ground bar won’t even take a #4 sounds very small indeed.  Your 2-2-2-4 is good for 90A *on each side* and you’re allowed to greatly oversubscribe breakers (so you could have 400-600A of breakers in this panel if you wanted to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your service cable is AL, then you need noalox goop on all the AL connections. You could pig tail the #4 to #6 (with goop) and then to the ground bar, but wouldn't it be easier just to get a ground bar that can accept #4? They aren't that expensive.

Updating my answer based upon Ed Beal's feedback.  I think this is what he's talking about, hopefully he can confirm.
[image: Chair fitting????? Ed, please confirm.]

Comment: doers that go under the screw at the top of the bar or into the bar?

Comment: Into the bar just like the other wires.   Be sure to see Ed's comment below. Apparently they are not approved everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If I have an issue I add a chair lug and screw it directly to the buss, years ago we used to split the wires into 2 equal groups but I think they quit allowing that back in 99 maybe prior, I usually carry a few single and double lug chair Lugs with my crimps ( I carry probably 50 lbs of different sized crimps) just for this reason. I do agree with George noalox or another corrosion inhibitor is needed with aluminum wire connections (I use it on all my feeders even copper).

Comment: I think the part number he needs is a TNLK20 or a TGL20CP.

Comment: Ed:  by a "Chair" do you mean a lug that has two legs that can fit into the ground bar with a larger screw/lug to accept the #4 wire?   I know you guys in the trades have your terms and slang, but for those of us that aren't in the trades, it's helpful for you guys to better describe the component you're talking about.  Still an up vote for your answer!  As JACK would say, "stay safe out there". +

Comment: The proper term is chair lug the one you show is just split to fit under 2 screws in the buss, they are allowed but in my county the inspector will find other issues as they consider this the same as splitting the wires , they want a bolt in a hole so it cannot come out they are the same with ground lugs in stranded rings no forks.